# non async method inside promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm new to node js and trying to understand how async code works. In the below example, would `nonAsyncMethod` have a race condition when checking if an array contains an item or is the `nonAsyncMethod` blocking?

```
async function example(inputs) {
    const array = [];
    await Promise.all(inputs.map(async (input) => {
        syncMethod(input, array);
    }));
}
function nonAsyncMethod(input, array) {
    if (!array.includes(input)) {
        array.push(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: The map method will not finish until the `syncMethod` finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map()` and `nonAsyncMethod()` are entirely synchronous.  Since Javascript runs your main Javascript thread as a single thread, everything here will be sequential (one at a time) and there are no race conditions or opportunities for race conditions.

There is also no reason to use `Promise.all()` at all here with synchronous code.  It offers no benefit and just unnecessarily complicates the code. You aren't returning anything from the `.map()` callback so you will be calling `Promise.all()` on an array of `undefined` values so it won't do anything useful.

What will happen here is the interpreter will call `inputs.map()`.  That will find the first item in `inputs` and then call the callback you passed to `.map()`.  When that callback returns, its return value will be added to the result array and then and only then will `.map()` advance to the next item in the array and call the next callback.  Since your callback is entirely synchronous, everything just runs in the expected sequence with no opportunity for race conditions.

That fact that you've wrapped your `.map()` in a `Promise.all()` does not change the `.map()` behavior at all.  Also keep in mind that the `.map()` runs before the `Promise.all()` does.

> would nonAsyncMethod have a race condition when checking if an array contains an item or is the nonAsyncMethod blocking?

No.

Comment: *completely synchronous*? Do you have some scale in percentages of *synchronousness*? I wonder how 10% synchronous function would look like ;)

Comment: @marzelin - All I mean is that everything in there is synchronous.

Comment: I know, but if there was one async line in the code would that function be 99% percent synchronous? Or would it be asynchronous, eh?

Comment: @marzelin - First off, declaring a function `async` does not make anything asynchronous.  But including ANY asynchronous operation inside the code block makes at least part of the operation be asynchronous (not entirely synchronous).  Percentages are meaningless here.  You're either entirely synchronous or you're not.

Comment: that's a good point. `async` function isn't entirely asynchronous - it's synchronous till the first `await`.

Comment: @marzelin - Yes.  Like the OP's callback they pass to `.map()` which they label as `async`, but has no asynchronous operations in it so it's just a synchronous function that returns a promise that is immediately resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're going to call these functions one after another? Then in that case they should run just as sync code. The reason is JavaScript uses only one thread for main execution and as long as something deferring the execution (like `setTimeout` or AJAX request) it's going to execute all synchronous code, even inside `async` functions, in normal order.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` accepts `Array` of `promises` .

`async` is only required if the function using `await` inside it

Here : `async` is valid since we have `await` inside the function.

```js
async function example(inputs) {
    const array = [];
    await Promise.all([promises]);
}
```

Adding `non promise` function `nonAsyncMethod` wont help because it is not promise.